# Replicate the CMD "timeout" countdown to be printed in a custom echo

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop, cmd

I've put together a batch script intended to be used by end users. For no particular functional purpose other than to make the user think something is going on, I'd like to make the script wait a few seconds before it continues executing. On Vista and later, this can be easily accomplished with `TIMEOUT /3`.

However, I'd like to replace the default output of the `TIMEOUT` command with my own custom output, *whilst retaining its countdown function*. As far as I know, `TIMEOUT` nor the equivalent `PING` or `SLEEP` methods support this, so this would have to be done manually, and I'm wondering what the **simplest way** to accomplish it is.

Comment: Try `sleepx.exe` from the [Shell Scripting Toolkit](http://www.westmesatech.com/sst.html).

Comment: Please read the question. The script is not for use on my personal machine, so it has to work independently of any dependencies. To elaborate, anything used must be native commands for Vista and above, at least.

Comment: You didn't say that you could not include an external executable, and you asked for something simple. Hence my comment.

Comment: I probably should have made it clearer, sorry.

Comment: @Hashim, regardless of your external dependencies, there are ways to embed standalone executable files into a batch file so they are portable with the batch file itself.

Comment: Ways that don't involve running more than the one batch file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All `TIMEOUT` does is count from the time `t` you gave it to wait till 0. So you can actually do the same by doing the following:

1. print something (with `t` if you want)
2. wait 1 second
3. print something (with `t-1`)
4. wait 1 second
   ...

You'll probably want to print everything on one line. You can do so  by printing a carriage return at the end of a line: the effect will be that you will be able to overwrite the line (the content won't exactly be deleted, but just overwritten). Here is a trick to get the carriage return character **with delayed expansion enabled**:

```
FOR /F %%a IN ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') DO set "carret=%%a"
```

This will put the carriage return character in the `carret` variable.

Now the print...You won't be able to use `echo` to print, it will still end each of your input with a carriage return and a newline character (you'll end up on a new line after each `echo` and the carriage return will be of no use anymore). So you'll have to use `set /p`. It allows you to print without carriage return and newline: `set /p =print something<nul`.

So your batch will look like this:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM countdown of 5 seconds
set count=5

REM prepare carriage return
FOR /F %%a IN ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') DO set "carret=%%a"

:ONE_SEC
REM print message
set /p =%count% seconds to go...!carret!<nul
REM wait one sec
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul 2>&1
REM decrement
set /a count-=1
IF %count% GTR 0 goto :ONE_SEC

REM last print, now you can use echo but don't forget: you have to override each character of the previous print! so fill all remaining place with whitespaces
echo Done waiting...   
REM  X seconds to go...

EndLocal
exit /b 0
```

**EDIT**: Because the carriage return only allows to override the previously printed line, you'll have to add whitespaces if what is printed after the carriage return won't completely cover what was printed previously. This is what happens with the last `echo`: `Done waiting...` is shorter than `X seconds to go...` so it won't fully overwrite it:

```
Done waiting...   
X seconds to go...
   from here ->   <- untill here: characters that won't be overwritten
```

It overwrites only until the o of `go` so the trailing dots `...` of the `X seconds to go...` will still be visible and you'll end up with

```
Done waiting......
```

The solution is to overwrite those exceeding characters with whitespaces (3 exceeding characters -> 3 whitespaces). So the last echo should be

```
echo Done waiting...<SPACE><SPACE><SPACE>
```

Replace `<SPACE>` with a real whitespace. I added it in the code above also but it isn't visible.

Also I'd like to thank [@LotPing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41273482/7170434) whose [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41273482/7170434) let me realise you could actually replace everything from the label `:ONE_SEC` to the `IF...goto ONE_SEC` with a `FOR /L` like he did:

```
FOR /L %%S IN (%count%, -1, 1) DO (
    set /p =%%S seconds to go...!carret!<nul
    ping -n 2 127.0.0.1 > nul 2>&1
)
```

I replaced the "less stable" `timeout` for the wait. `timeout /N` will wait between `N-1` and `N` seconds, would be ok for large `N` but with `N=1` can lead to some issues. (effect of waiting 0.3 seconds instead of 1 is not the same as 149.3 instead of 150 for example).
The extra `set /p` before the loop wasn't needed for me.

Comment: This is genius, and behaves almost exactly as I expected, so thanks so much for this. There are a few minor issues that prevent this from behaving exactly like the `TIMEOUT` counter. I managed to solve all but one. The first and simplest is that the `TIMEOUT` counter counts down to 0, whereas this solution counts to 1 before it stops. Setting the IF statement to check for a count of -1 instead of 0 solves this, though probably in a crude way.

Comment: The second issue is that if there's no space between the last character in the "seconds to go" prompt and the `!carret!`, that last character is printed twice - in the above case, a period. Oddly, this only occurs once the first number has been echoed - so everything looks normal on 5, but on 4 and subsequent numbers, there's a repeat character. Thirdly, on the very first number but none of the subsequent ones, the number is followed by a semicolon. Possibly related to the second issue, because this one occurs on the numbers that that one doesn't, and that one occurs where this one doesn't.

Comment: Hopefully those two issues can be solved to make this solution a perfect alternative. Still, once again, thanks for this, I'd never have known to do what you did.

Comment: The first issue you explain is kind of counter intuitive for me. If I would see `0 seconds to go...` I would actually expect it to stop (that I don't have to wait anymore). Off course if it would print `0.5 seconds to go...` it would be ok(but I don't know how to add that precision). Anyway don't forget that in the case you add the print for 0, you're waiting a second longer (the second you wait when the 0 is on screen). You can make it accept the 0 also by replacing `GTR` in the [`IF`](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) with `GEQ` (greater or equal)

Comment: I can't really understand the second issue you're describing. It is probably not because each number adds a character but because the last sentence `Done waiting...` doesn't completely overwrite the rest. I've edited my answer and provided some more explanation. I hope it solves the issue.

Comment: I understand it's an extra second, yes, and I suppose it is a little counter-intuitive, but for the sake of one more second, it's personally worth it for the purpose of making it as close as possible to usual CMD behaviour. Thanks for the heads up about the GEQ operator, I wasn't aware of that one. I'll rewrite my version to include that instead of the more hacky -1.

Comment: With regards to the second issue, I should have mentioned that I seem to have solved it by adding an extra space. The only issue that now persists is the third one, which is also the most noticeable - the random semicolon after the first number in the countdown. Directly after the number 5, a semicolon `;` gets printed, which then disappears once the countdown hits 4 and all the subsequent numbers. I'm curious about what's causing that bug, and would ideally like to get rid of it.

Comment: I am still not able to understand or reproduce your second and third issue. Everything works fine on my Windows 10 machine. Even the semicolon isn't appearing. Maybe check the initialization of the `count` variable. I can remember in my very first version I had added a semicolon by mistake(little habit from Java project I was working on) but I removed that one right away (like seconds or some minute after I posted the answer). Could it be possible you've copied that version?

Comment: Nope, no semicolon in the script that I can find. Here's my full script, with URL variables removed: http://pastebin.com/Y5k78Sw5.

Comment: Yes, the line initializing `count`, line 10, contains a semicolon at the end: `SET count=5;`

Comment: Wow. I'm an idiot. Suppose I was blind to it too - Javascript background. :P Thanks, man, that makes this script exactly like I intended. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the problem, as well as you can suppress i.e. the pause output with

```
Echo My own hint to press any key
Pause >NUL
```

you can do with timeout.

Kudos to J.Baoby for the carret, a count down loop is a bit simpler than a manual one.
The first set /P in the loop doesn't seem to echo the nummber - so I put one in front.

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

REM countdown of 5 seconds
set /A count=15

REM prepare carriage return
FOR /F %%a IN ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') DO set "carret=%%a"

set /p =%count% seconds to go...!carret!  <nul
For /L %%S in (%Count%,-1,1) Do (
  set /p =%%S seconds to go...!carret!  <nul
  Timeout /T 1 >NUL
)
echo Done waiting...
```

To have a longer countdown not leaving chars behind some spaces should be added to the end of the prompt. To be able to interrupt the countdown you can exchange timeout with choice and checking errorlevel in the loop.